# Chaining jQuery.each()

Tags: method-chaining, jquery

I'm trying to add results from an object to newly created HTML elements:

```
*long chain of newly created elements*.append(
    $("<div />").append(
        $.each(myObj.results, function( intIndex, objValue ){
            return objValue.description;
        })
    )
);
```

If I use a function() call with a for-loop instead of each() it works, but is there no way to achieve this with each()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.each` is meant for iterating over the list and perform operation, You can achieve what you want with [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) Which build an array from returned elements in each iteration.

```
*long chain of newly created elements*.append(
    $("<div />").append(function(){
        var des = $.map(myObj.results, function( objValue ){
                     return objValue.description;
                  });
        return des.join(' ');
      });
);
```

Answer (score 3):

.each just iterates through a collection, you need an anonymous function to return something, so try this:

```
$("<div />").append(function(){
        var string = "":
        $.each(myObj.results, function( intIndex, objValue ){
               string += objValue.description;
            })
        return string;
    });
```